# aura component for the flow - set some design attributes to input only and some to output Only

Tags: visual-workflow, aura

I have an action in the flow which calls an aura component. The aura component is supplied with the id of the record. How do I make the id of the record input only as I dont want that attribute show up on the manually assign variables section of the action setup window. Below is my code, here I want the input only variables which caseId & opportunityId to show up on the Set Input values section and output only variable which is remain to show up on the Manually assign variables section.

**When I tried to push the below code it says Invalid attribute role.**

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="caseId" label="Case ID" role="inputOnly" />
    <design:attribute name="opportunityId" label="Opportunity ID" role="inputOnly" />
    <design:attribute name="remain" label="Remain" role="outputOnly"/>
</design:component>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *role* attribute is only documented for [Lightning Web Components (LWC)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags)

In Aura, [Design Attribute Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_tips_attributes.htm) and [Aura Component Bundle Design Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) mentions the only attributes Flow Builder supports:

> Supported Attributes on design:attribute Nodes
>
> In a design:attribute node, **Flow Builder supports only the name, label, description, and
> default attributes**. The other attributes, like min and max, are
> ignored.

As such, you won't be able to do designate it as *inputOnly* in Aura. You'd have to convert your Aura component into a Lightning Web Component.